# be maked Infinite loop in python.3

Tags: python-3.x, loops, input, client, infinite-loop

i want to make one server and client in the python.3
this is my server:

```
import socket

ip =('192.168.1.101',12345)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(ip)

s.listen(1)

print('Server is ready')

client , addr = s.accept()

print('one client has conected to me'+str(addr))

while True:

    a = input('what do you want to tell ? ')
    if a == 'q':
        break

    a=a.encode('utf_8')

    client.sendall(a)

client.close()
```

and my client is :

```
import socket

ip = ('192.168.1.101', 12345)
conecttion = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

conecttion.connect(ip)

while True:
    data = conecttion.recv(1024)
    
    if data == 'q':
        break
print(data)

    
conecttion.close()
```

but when i send 'q' in the client be maked Infinite loop.
what should i to do when i send 'q' the conection be closed.
who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- On the server, you are not sending 'q'. You are breaking before the send.
- On the client, the received data is binary so you need to convert to a character.

Try this code:

Server:

```
import socket

ip =('127.0.0.1',12345)  # local machine
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(ip)
s.listen(1)

print('Server is ready')

client , addr = s.accept()

print('one client has conected to me'+str(addr))

while True:
    a = input('what do you want to tell ? ')
    aa=a.encode('utf_8')
    client.sendall(aa)  # byte data
    if a == 'q':   # original string
        break

client.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket, time

ip = ('127.0.0.1', 12345)    # local machine
conecttion = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

conecttion.connect(ip)

while True:
    data = conecttion.recv(1024)
    
    if data and chr(data[0]) == 'q':
        break
        
    print(data)

conecttion.close()
```